# Not Receiving Email from Batch apex

Tags: email

I want to send email containing details of the opportunity that is being executed by the batch apex. I am trying to Automatically close the opportunity that has not been closed on the desired date and then a email must send containing details of opp. that has been closed.
I am not getting any error on developer console but even unable to receive mail.
Here is my Code:

```
global class oppstage implements Database.Batchable<sObject> 
{
    List<Opportunity> updatedOpps = new List<Opportunity>(); // List for storing Opportunities
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) 
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(Label.oppStageLabel);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> records) 
    {
        for (Opportunity obj : records) 
        {
            Date Extra10 = obj.CloseDate.addDays(10);
            if (Extra10 == Date.today()) 
            {
                obj.StageName = 'Closed Won';
                updatedOpps.add(obj); // Adding updated opportunity
            }
        }
        if (!updatedOpps.isEmpty()) 
        {
            update updatedOpps; 
        }
        system.debug('updatedopps in execute : '+updatedopps);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        List<String> idList = new List<String>();
        List<String> mailToAddresses = new List<String>(); 
        Group gp = [SELECT (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM Group WHERE Name = 'BatchGrp'];
        for (GroupMember gm : gp.GroupMembers) 
        {
            idList.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);
        }
        List<User> userList = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :idList];
        for(User u : userList) 
        {
            mailToAddresses.add(u.email);
        }
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        system.debug('updatedopps : '+updatedopps);
        for (Opportunity opp : updatedOpps) 
        { 
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.setToAddresses(mailToAddresses);
            message.setSubject('Opportunity Stage Update');
            message.setPlainTextBody('The Opportunity has been updated to Closed Won. Opportunity Name: ' + opp.Name);
            emailMessages.add(message);
        }
        if (!emailMessages.isEmpty()) 
        {
            Messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Database.Stateful` in order to store data between batchable transactions. You're not getting any email, because there are no opportunities in the list of updated records. In addition, you're needlessly updating the records that have already been updated. On top of that, there shouldn't be an if statement in your `execute` method. Also, your code is extremely wasteful by emailing a separate email for every single opportunity to every single user, and needlessly burning up your daily email limits by using email addresses instead of user IDs.

Here's a simple refactor that accounts for most of this:

```
public class oppstage implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    List<Opportunity> updatedOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(Label.oppStageLabel);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> records) {
        for(Opportunity record : records) {
            record.StageName = 'Closed Won';
        }
        update records;
        updatedOpps.addAll(records);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        List<GroupMember> groupMembers = [SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.Name = 'BatchGrp'];
        Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(GroupMember groupMember : groupMembers) {
            if(groupMember.UserOrGroupId.getSobjectType() == User.sObjectType) {
                userIds.add(groupMember.UserOrGroupId);
            }
        }
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Opportunity opp:updatedOpps) { 
            for(Id userId:userIds) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                message.setTargetObjectId(userId);
                message.setSubject('Opportunity Stage Update');
                message.setPlainTextBody('The Opportunity has been updated to Closed Won. Opportunity Name: ' + opp.Name);
                emailMessages.add(message);
            }
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages);
    }
}
```

I wrongly recommend that you just make a list of records that were updated and put them into a single email message to avoid spamming the users.